# The file_get_contents function. Does its path support reversing a directory?

Tags: php

Basically

```
file_get_contents('test.php')
```

works perfectly. However,

```
file_get_contents('/../test.php')
```

results in `"file_get_contents(/../xx.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory"`

The directory structure is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say the directory structure is correct, but it still seems odd to read:

```
file_get_contents('/../test.php')
```

Are you sure it shouldn’t be as follows without the leading slash:

```
file_get_contents('../test.php')
```

Comment: You're dead right. What I meant was that the folders were correct, not necessarily the path. Thanks!